# Jar files inside another jar error NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have created jar file which contains dependent jar but when I try to run the class file inside that it gives error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at com.TestFlowProcessor.<clinit>(WebMethodsFlowProcessor.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

My Manifest file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: test
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_45
Class-Path: log4j-1.2.17.jar slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar commons-logging-1.1.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar jsoup-1.8.3.jar junit-3.8.1.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar poi-3.8-20120326.jar poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar SAPIntegrationDirectory.jar stax-api-1.0.1.jar xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
Main-Class: com.TestFlowProcessor
```

I am trying to execute using 
java -cp WMTOFuse.jar com.TestFlowProcessor

Comment: Generally speaking, the classloader won't load jars which are embedded within jars. You could have a look at the OneJar project for a possible solution

Comment: Instead of making a 'fat' jar file, you can keep the dependent jars inside a folder (e.g. lib) and then use java -cp <folder>/lib*:WMTOFuse.jar com.TestFlowProcessor. Change : to ; if in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'Ant' 'jar' task for this. Refer https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

```
<jar destfile="build/main/checksites.jar">
    <fileset dir="build/main/classes"/>
    <restrict>
     <name name="**/*.class"/>
     <archives>
       <zips>
         <fileset dir="lib/main" includes="**/*.jar"/>
       </zips>
     </archives>
    </restrict>
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class"
            value="com.acme.checksites.Main"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
```

above creates a single jar file containing inside it contents of multiple jars.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is seems to be with log4j-1.2.17.jar. I have changed it to
>   log4j-1.2.15.jar & above mentioned issue is resolved. Thanks everyone
>   for helping me out with this.